# Replace C style comments by C++ style comments

Tags: c++, comments

How can I automatically replace all C style comments (`/* comment */`) by C++ style comments (`// comment`)?

This has to be done automatically in several files. Any solution is okay, as long as it works.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to do this? A C++ compiler will compile the C-style comments just fine, so what's the point? You might not want to add any more c-style comments, but leaving the old ones alone shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: I agree with Michael.  Besides, you stir up the CVS.

Comment: And why the heck would anybody call this question offensive?

Comment: This question is a waste of time. Not from parsing point of view, but the pointless task it tries to achieve.

Comment: I gotta disagree with Tanveer, even though I side with the others who say not to do it.  But for those of us with a touch of code-OCD, it's the next step after indenting and beautification.  However, sometimes you gotta know where to draw the line... so I guess he's got to find out somehow.

Comment: I'm guessing that the offensive flag was for a (edited out) remark about a particular product.

Comment: -1 Tanveer.  Maybe this was a decree that came from on high.  If management tells you to dig a hole then fill it in again, sometimes you just have to do it despite the pointlessness.

Comment: From a practical point of view, this is a pointless exercise (even if your managers are idiots - why would you want to work for idiots in the first place?)  From an academic point of view, Darron has the right answer.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons that you need to do this. Maybe you have some kind of preprocessor or other tool. Maybe you just have a coding convention that you need to follow. There's nothing pointless about asking how to restructure text: we making our livings from carefully structured text.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This tool does the job:
https://github.com/cenit/jburkardt/tree/master/recomment

> RECOMMENT is a C++ program which
> converts C style comments to C++ style
> comments.

It also handles all the non-trivial cases mentioned by other people:

> This code incorporates suggestions and
> coding provided on 28 April 2005 by
> Steven Martin of JDS Uniphase,
> Melbourne Florida. These suggestions
> allow the program to ignore the
> internal contents of strings, (which
> might otherwise seem to begin or end
> comments), to handle lines of code
> with trailing comments, and to handle
> comments with trailing bits of code.

Comment: Unfortunately, RECOMMENT does not handle indentation and formatting very well, and it does not support Doxygen comments at all. That is why I created [c-comments-to-cpp](https://github.com/mbitsnbites/c-comments-to-cpp).

Answer (score 11):

This is not a trivial problem.

```
int * /* foo 
  /* this is not the beginning of a comment.

int * */ var = NULL;
```

What do you want to replace that with?  Any real substitution requires sometimes splitting lines.

```
int * // foo
  // this is not the beginning of a comment.
// int *
var = NULL;
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 5):

How do you intend to handle situations like this:

```
void CreateExportableDataTable(/*[out, retval]*/ IDispatch **ppVal)
{
 //blah
}
```

Note the comment inside the parens... this is a common way of documenting things in generated code, or mentioning default parameter values in the implementation of a class, etc.  I'm usually not a fan of such uses of comments, but they are common and need to be considered.  I don't think you can convert them to C++ style comments without doing some heavy thinking.

Comment: there is a fairly easy (but undesirable solution). Every comment you replace if it doesn't end with 0 or whitespace chars and a newline, you insert a newline. So in other words "IDispatch **ppVal)" would be on a new line.

Comment: don't get me wrong, i agree with you that the conversion is a bad idea

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm with the people who commented in your question.  Why do it?  Just leave it.

it wastes time, adds useless commits to version control, risk of screwing up

EDIT:
Adding details from the comments from the OP

> The fundamental reason of preferring C++-style comment is that you can comment out a block of code which may have comments in it. If that comment is in C-style, this block-comment-out of code is not straight forward. – unknown (yahoo)

that might be a fair/ok thing to want to do, but I have two comments about that:

- I know of no one who would advocate changing all existing code - that is a preference for new code. (IMO)
- If you feel the need to "comment out code" (another iffy practice) then you can do it as needed - not before

It also appears that you want to use the c-style comments to block out a section of code?  Or are you going to use the // to block out many lines?

One alternative is a preprocessor #ifdef for that situation.  I cringe at that but it is just as bad as commenting out lines/blocks.  Neither should be left in the production code.

Comment: The fundamental reason of preferring C++-style comment is that you can comment out a block of code which may have comments in it. If that comment is in C-style, this block-comment-out of code is not straight forward.

Comment: Fair enough. two points: 1. I know of no one who would advocate changing all existing code - that is a preference for new code.  (IMO) 2. If you feel the need to "comment out code" (another iffy practice) then you can do it as needed - not before.

Comment: In my editor, commenting out a block of code which may have comments in it is straightforward and requires only two keystrokes. Uncommenting is equally straightforward. Why go through so much trouble when you can just use a decent editor?

Comment: -1 as this does answer the op's question, and is mostly just saying the idea is stupid. That's what comments are for.

Answer (score 3):

I recently converted all C-style comments to C++-style for all files in our repository. Since I could not find a tool that would do it automatically, I wrote my own: [c-comments-to-cpp](https://github.com/mbitsnbites/c-comments-to-cpp)

It is not fool-proof, but way better than anything else I've tried (including RECOMMENT). Among other things, it supports converting Doxygen style comments, for instance:

```
/**
* @brief My foo struct.
*/
struct foo {
  int bar;  /*!< This is a member.
                 It also has a meaning. */
};
```

Gets converted to:

```
/// @brief My foo struct.
struct foo {
  int bar;  ///< This is a member.
            ///< It also has a meaning.
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python script that will (mostly) do the job.  It handles most edge cases, but it does not handle comment characters inside of strings, although that should be easy to fix.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

out = ''
in_comment = False

file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r+')
for line in file:
    if in_comment:
        end = line.find('*/')
        if end != -1:
            out += '//' + line[:end] + '\n'
            out += ' ' * (end + 2) + line[end+2:]
            in_comment = False
        else:
            out += '//' + line
    else:
        start = line.find('/*')
        cpp_start = line.find('//')
        if start != -1 and (cpp_start == -1 or cpp_start > start):
            out += line[:start] + '//' + line[start+2:]
            in_comment = True
        else:
            out += line

file.seek(0)
file.write(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a C app to parse it's own source files?  You could find the /* comments */ sections with a relatively easy Regex query.  You could then replace the new line characters with new line character + "//".

Anyway, just a thought.  Good luck with that.

Comment: Why on earth would you do this in C? There are loads of languages far more suited to regex search-replace than C. Plus, why would it parse "it's own" source files?

Comment: Well I could say doing it in C just because presumably the OP already knows C. Having said that, I would say that avoiding the relative pain of doing it in C would be well worth the effort of learning a better language for this task. Personally I would suggest Python, but there are lots of choices.

Comment: Regular expressions are insufficient anyway, a real parser will be needed.

Comment: Of course, if you could get your hands on the source code for an ANSI compliant C++ compiler, then you have a parser. :)

Comment: Agree with Darron - you can't use regex on, for example, 
printf("////**** this better not be changed, it's a string literal!\n");
A real C parser is needed.

Comment: I would worry about a source repository where you couldn't hack together a regex that was "good enough", and then fix up any problems by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you write an application/script to process the C source files, here are some things to be careful of:

- comment characters within strings
- comment characters in the middle of a line (you might not want to split the code line)

You might be better off trying to find an application that understands how to actually parse the code as code.

Answer (score 0):

If there are just "several files" is it really necessary to write a program? Opening it up in a text editor might do the trick quicker in practice, unless there's a whole load of comments. emacs has a `comment-region` command that (unsurprisingly) comments a region, so it'd just be a case of ditching the offending '/*' and '*/'.

Comment: +1. Many text editors will also ‘find and replace in files’. You will in any case need a quick visual check, for all the corner-cases mentioned by other posters.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few suggestions that you might like to try out:

a)Write your own code (C/ Python/ any language you like) to replace the comments. Something along the lines of what regex said or this naive solution **'might'** work:
[Barring cases like the one rmeador, Darron posted]

```
 
for line in file:
    if line[0] == "\*":
       buf = '//' + all charachters in the line except '\*'
       flag = True
    if flag = True:
       if line ends with '*/':
          strip off '*/'
          flag = False
       add '//' + line to buf
```

b)Find a tool to do it. (I'll look up some and post, if I find them.)

c)Almost all modern IDE's (if you are using one) or text editors have an auto comment feature. You can then manually open up each file, select comment lines, decide how to handle the situation and comment C++ style using an accelerator (say Ctrl + M). Then, you can simply 'Find and Replace' all "/*" and "*/", again using your judgment. I have Gedit configured to do this using the "Code Comment' plugin. I don't remember the way I did it in Vim off hand. I am sure this one can be found easily.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, I know, but I just achieved this using "pure emacs". In short, the solution looks as follows:

Run `M-x query-replace-regexp`. When prompted, enter

```
/\*\(\(.\|^J\)*?\)*\*/
```

as the regex to search for. The `^J` is a newline, which you can enter by pressing `^Q` (Ctrl+Q in most keyboards), and then pressing the enter key. Then enter

```
//\,(replace-regexp-in-string "[\n]\\([ ]*?\\)   \\([^ ]\\)" "\n\\1// \\2" \1))
```

as the replacement expression.

Essentially, the idea is that you use two nested regex searches. The main one simply finds C-style comments (the `*?` eager repetition comes very handy for this). Then, an elisp expression is used to perform a second replacement *inside the comment text only*. In this case, I'm looking for newlines followed by space, and replacing the last three space characters by `//`, which is nice for preserving the comment formatting (works only as long as all comments are indented, though).

Changes to the secondary regex will make this approach work in other cases, for example

```
//\,(replace-regexp-in-string "[\n]" " " \1))
```

will just put the whole contents of the original comment into a single C++-style comment.

Comment: A quick and dirty and ignorant of all corner cases solution to convert one-line-c-comments to one-line-cpp-comments in Visual Studio (MSVC) might be: Search=/\*[ \t]*([^/*]*)[ \t]*\*/ Replace=// $1

Answer (score -3):

from PHP team convention... some reasonning has to exist if the question was asked. Just answer if you know.

> Never use C++ style comments (i.e. // comment).  Always use C-style
>       comments instead.  PHP is written in C, and is aimed at compiling
>       under any ANSI-C compliant compiler.  Even though many compilers
>       accept C++-style comments in C code, you have to ensure that your
>       code would compile with other compilers as well.
>       The only exception to this rule is code that is Win32-specific,
>       because the Win32 port is MS-Visual C++ specific, and this compiler
>       is known to accept C++-style comments in C code.