# sed replace (single-line) C comments with C++ comments

Tags: regex, sed

How can i use sed to replace all my C-style comments in a source file to C++ style.

All these:

```
int main() {
  /* some comments */
  ...
```

to:

```
int main() {
  // some comments
  ...
```

All comments are single line and there are none in between code like this:

```
int f(int x /*x-coordinate*/ );
```

so I tried this:

```
 sed -i 's/ \/\* .*  \*\ / \/\/* /g' src.c
```

but it leaves the file unchanged.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542006/replace-c-style-comments-by-c-style-comments) post is similar, but I'm trying to understand sed's expression syntax.  Since "." matches any character and " * " matches zero or more of some pattern. I assume ".*" matches any number of any character.

Comment: This's my first time hearing the names "C comments" and "C++ comments"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed -i 's:\(.*\)/[*]\(.*\)[*]/:\1 // \2:' FILE
```

this will transform each line like this :

```
aaa  /* test */
```

into a line like this:

```
aaa  // test
```

If you have more comments on the same line, you can apply this more sophisticated parser, that converts a line like:

```
aaa /* c1 */ bbb /* c2 */ ccc
```

into

```
aaa  bbb ccc // c1 c2
```

---

```
sed -i ':r s:\(.*\)/[*]\(.*\)[*]/\(.*\):\1\3 //\2:;tr;s://\(.*\)//\(.*\)://\2\1:;tr' FILE
```

A more sophisticated case is when you have comments inside strings on a line, like in `call("/*string*/")`. Here is a script `c-comments.sed`, to solve this problem:

```
s:\(["][^"]*["]\):\n\1\n:g
s:/[*]:\n&:g
s:[*]/:&\n:g
:r
s:["]\([^\n]*\)\n\([^"]*\)":"\1\2":g
tr
:x
s:\(.*\)\n/[*]\([^\n]*\)[*]/\n\(.*\)$:\1\3 // \2:
s:\(.*\)\n\(.*\)//\(.*\)//\(.*\):\1\n\2 //\4\3:
tx
s:\n::g
```

You save this script into a file c-comments.sed, and you call it like this:

```
sed -i -f c-comments.sed FILE
```

Comment: it is a separator. The next char after the command 's' is called a separator, and can be any char. For example, if the string I need to replace contain '/', it is bad to insert '/' as separator, because in this case I would be obliged to quote with backslash the '/'. In this case I used ':'