# How to edit source files: need to trim comment blocks at the top of each source file?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Currently, we need to pass our source codes to the client company. But all of the source files contain standard author and copyright comment blocks at top of each source file, so we need to trim that text. The project structure should be preserved. the What command or utility would be best to use, any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check here:
[sed replace (single-line) C comments with C++ comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730287/sed-replace-single-line-c-comments-with-c-comments)

As you have tagged the question ios, you have access to bash (and sed). Sed uses regex to find/replace text. Modifying the regex in the link above should be trivial.

Edit:

Here is sed script which will remove all c and c++ comments: http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/remccoms3.sed (Courtesy of Brian Hiles)

Download it, place it with your source, and run

```
./remccoms3 <SourceFile.cpp >NewSourceFile.cpp
```