# Regular expression comments

Tags: regex

I have two types of comments
`//` and `/*...*/`
I need to match `/*...*/` and pick all the data between these comments.
Then add //+ to all the data including /* and */ so it will look like:

```
//+/*
//+ line 1
//+ line 2
//+*/
```

The same file has comments marked as `//` and these should not be picked.
Using the following regular expression it is picking every line which starts with `/`

`^[ \t]*[\/\*] .*`

```
^[ \t]*[\*\/].*
```

What would be the correct regular expression to identify the start and end of `/*` and `*/` comments.
Thanks.

Update:
Can there be a expression to get an exact match of `/*` or `*/`?
For searching `/*` I used `\/*.` but if `//` is encounter it also picks it.

Comment: This problem is actually very very tricky to handle in the general case.  I've solved this before but it wasn't a super simple regex.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542006/replace-c-style-comments-by-c-style-comments?

Answer (score 4):

I have written [an entire article on figuring out the regular expression for comments](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html).  It isn't a trivial problem.  The end result is:

```
 (/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)
```

Its also worth pointing out this major caveat:

> ### Comments Inside Other Elements
>
> Although our regular expression describes c-style comments very well, there are still problems when something appears to be a comment but is actually part of a larger element.

```
someString = "An example comment: /* example */";
 
// The comment around this code has been commented out.
// /*
some_code();
// */
```

> The solution to this is to write regular expressions that describe each of the possible larger elements, find these as well, decide what type of element each is, and discard the ones that are not comments. There are tools called lexers or tokenizers that can help with this task. A lexer accepts regular expressions as input, scans a stream, picks out tokens that match the regular expressions, and classifies the token based on which expression it matched. The greedy property of regular expressions is used to ensure the longest match. Although writing a full lexer for C is beyond the scope of this document, those interested should look at lexer generators such as [Flex](http://www.gnu.org/software/flex/flex.html) and [JFlex](http://jflex.de/).

Regular expressions are not the correct way to convert block comments to line comments.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542006/replace-c-style-comments-by-c-style-comments) asks how to do it using any method.  There are tools that will do a much better job than regular expressions.  The accepted answer recommends the software [recomment](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Eburkardt/cpp_src/recomment/recomment.html).

Comment: Thanks for the article. Would the correct regular expression only to pick the opening and closing comments (/* and */) would be: /\*.*\*/. Tried this but does not get /*. To simplify I am looking at one line only and don't need to pick the block between the /* and */.