# Regular expressions exact match comment

Tags: regex

This is in follow up to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067950/regular-expression-comments).
What would be the regular expression to match exactly:

```
/*
```

When trying `\/*.` it pick `/*` but will also pick `//` or `*`

When trying `\*\/` it does pick exactly `*/` which is good so far.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a quantifier so you have to escape it too:

```
\/\*
```

Answer (score 0):

That regex will be this with anchors `^` and `$`:

```
^\/\*$
```